# PLSQL Get Variable By Loop Index

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I am trying to reach columns by loop index of a cursor record. Currently i am using multiple variables for each columns thus I think that I should refactor my codes. In java, I'd use reflection to do that but I stuck in PLSQL. Code will explain better

input is passed into from loop.

```
i_member_awd_rowtype    in member_awd%rowtype
.
.
.
--many more inputs
l_step1_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.flt_company;
l_step1_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.class_code;
l_step2_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.ret_flt_company;
l_step2_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.ret_class_code;
l_step3_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step3_company;
l_step3_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step3_class_code;
l_step4_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step4_company;
l_step4_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step4_class_code;
l_step5_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step5_company;
l_step5_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step5_class_code;
l_step6_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step6_company;
l_step6_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step6_class_code;
l_step7_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step7_company;
l_step7_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step7_class_code;
l_step8_company  := i_member_awd_rowtype.step8_company;
l_step8_subclass := i_member_awd_rowtype.step8_class_code;
```

I need to assign single class, company and subclass variables in a loop such as

```
/*for i in 1 .. 8 loop
        l_step_subclass := 
end loop;*/
```

Is there any way to write as I wanted in PLSQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code block containing a <kbd>[Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)</kbd> statement might be used, assuming you wanna gather the records for each identity column(`id`) of the table :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on 
SQL> declare
 v_tbl           varchar2(31) := 'member_awd';
 v_sql           varchar2(250); 
 v_id            member_awd.id%type := :p_id;
 type typ is     table of varchar2(32767) index by binary_integer; 
 l_step_subclass typ;
begin    
  for c in ( select column_id, column_name 
               from user_tab_columns 
              where table_name = upper(v_tbl) order by column_id )
  loop
    v_sql := 'select '||c.column_name||' from '||v_tbl||' where id = :i_id ';
    execute immediate v_sql into l_step_subclass(c.column_id) using v_id;     
    dbms_output.put_line(l_step_subclass(c.column_id));     
  end loop;
end;  
/
```

where the variable `l_step_subclass` is converted to the array type. This way, all values for each individual column are assigned to this column local variable.